# Why are some countries continuing to tighten lockdown restrictions despite empty hospitals and decreasing coronavirus infections?

Tags: covid-19, canada

As an example, British Columbia decided to shutdown all national parks on [April 8th](https://news.gov.bc.ca/releases/2020ENV0019-000645). This might seem prudent if we were talking about Lombardy in March, but the actual numbers show that BC is actually doing fantastic already. Note that these are actual hospitalisation numbers, which are by far more accurate than official testing counts.

[image]

Given the incredibly low numbers, why does BC attempt to restrict people moving around even more?

Comment: Can't say what the BC justification was, but if you implement lockdowns late (as Italy did) they are lot less effective in terms of overall deaths, even if the late lockdowns are "tight". Westerners are blasting China for not implementing their (Chinese/Wuhan) lockdowns sooner/earlier. (There was a [IIRC] Lancet paper on that, let me see if I can find it again.)

Comment: @Fizz BC has been in lockdown for a long time now and their infections have reached a plateau. It's not comparable to Wuhan in January or Bergamo in late February. It would be more akin to Wuhan suddenly deciding to tighten lockdowns in late February when the epidemic was on the downturn.

Comment: I am not the downvoter but the question seems a bit lazy to me. How did you determine these numbers are “fantastic”? A quick back-of-the-envelope calculation suggests the number of people in critical care is an order of magnitude better than in the worse affected countries (Italy, Spain, France) but that's still far from negligible. Raw numbers should of course be judged relative to the population and critical care capacity.

Comment: @Relaxed the numbers are fantastic because you could easily fit all COVID-19 patients from the entire province into a single hospital wing. It is equivalent to all of the EU having only 20k cases hospitalised.

Comment: Regarding that particular measure (closing parks), it's a minor adjustment, is not very restrictive, and the press release gives a clear rationale. Importantly, this curve provides zero evidence of a decrease, only a plateau (that's fortunately lower than in some other places) but that's the result of the current policy. Presumably, lifting restrictions would be tied to the situation in neighboring provinces/countries, a plan on how to avoid seeing community spread increase again and the general preparedness of the healthcare system, not merely a decrease that isn't there yet.

Comment: @JonathanReez Number of patients is not that important, critical care is and not all hospital have 60+ critical care beds. How many hospitals are there in BC in the first place?

Comment: @Relaxed there are [348 ICU beds dedicated to COVID patients](https://www.theglobeandmail.com/canada/british-columbia/article-bc-should-have-enough-beds-and-ventilators-for-covid-19-patients/) in British Columbia and that number could be expanded to 900+ if needed. So BC has been consistently using 20% of dedicated ICU capacity over the past two weeks. Fantastic numbers by any imaginable metric.

Comment: @Relaxed and I'm not asking about lifting existing restrictions - only about why new ones are introduced when it's obvious that current measures are more than sufficient.

Comment: @JonathanReez I was about to post [a similar number](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4426537/) but with a very different interpretation. Their capacity is not overloaded but it's actually much lower than in most comparable places. The fact that 60 is already 20% shows it is not safe to assume that a relatively low number is negligible and that assessment is entirely missing from your question.

Comment: @JonathanReez I already commented on that: It's really a minute adjustment of current rules, a technical adjustment rather than a meaningful tightening **and the press release offers several reasons**, including this: “The timing of this decision is important given the upcoming long weekend and the beginning of the busy season for outdoor recreation and camping. BC Parks is also extending the ban on all camping in provincial parks until May 31, 2020, in alignment with neighbouring jurisdictions and the temporary closure of Canada’s national parks.”

Comment: It's only if you are expecting them to lift restrictions because the number of patients is stable (not decreasing as your question still states) that there is anything puzzling about it. It seems to me you're misrepresenting the numbers and hyping a negligible measure to create a question that is unanswerable because it's based on fictional premises.

Comment: @Relaxed: instead of this back-and-forth in comments with  Jonathan, please write an answer. It seems you found out enough about what the BC officials said to answer the question, at least from their perspective.

Comment: @Fizz At this point the question is deep in the negative and as pointed out by several people suffers from many flaws. This could be an answer to a more reasonable question that didn't attempt to misrepresent this measure to score points.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine because [relaxing restrictions increase the probability of a strengthened second wave happening](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2020/04/200408184717.htm):

> "While these control measures appear to have reduced the number of infections to very low levels, without herd immunity against COVID-19, cases could easily resurge as businesses, factory operations, and schools gradually resume and increase social mixing, particularly given the increasing risk of imported cases from overseas as COVID-19 continues to spread globally," says Professor Joseph T Wu from the University of Hong Kong who co-led the research.

That is, while everything *looks okay*, it very well may not be okay. The minute they relax restrictions, covid-19 could make a come back.

If my understanding is correct, the longer the restrictions are in place, the longer they work, which ultimately will help *stunt the growth* of a second wave. But that's if my understanding of that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Probably for a number of reasons.  Note that the parks being shutdown are Provincial, not National(Federal).

First, not everyone is cooperative when it comes to distancing.  2 people sitting close to each other?  Might very well be people in the same household.  4 adults close together?  Errr, probably not.  And you still see a fair amount of that happening in our parks.  Some cities have therefore [shut down some of their beaches and parks](https://www.citynews1130.com/2020/04/08/white-rock-promenade-closed/).  The province is also doing that to things under their jurisdiction.  Campgrounds have been shut for more than 2 weeks now.

Second, when it comes to provincial parks, a number of them are in remote areas.  There is therefore a temptation to "ride out the storm" far away from bigger cities, by camping in a provincial park.  The trouble is that the smaller cities  do NOT have the hospital infrastructure to cope with large numbers of sick people.  The [cities themselves are already politely asking people to stay away](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/british-columbia/coastal-communities-call-for-travel-restrictions-as-visitors-trickle-in-1.5518460) and it makes sense to support that by shutting the parks down.

The flip side is that provincial health authorities are not ruling out considering relaxing the business restrictions somewhat outside of the big affected urban centres in the future.

Yes, we're doing rather better in BC than elsewhere.  And, yes, we'd like to keep it that way.  There is a great deal of pride and appreciation in the work of our chief medical officer, Bonnie Henry.  The sooner we can get to much more limited numbers, the sooner we can get to a South Korean level of "normalcy".  But we are nowhere near fully throttling propagation yet and *doing fantastic already* is hardly something I associate with having 60 odd people on ICUs, half of which could statistically be expected not to survive.

For those who are interested in official BC covid communications, here's the [horse's mouth](http://www.bccdc.ca/health-info/diseases-conditions/covid-19/case-counts-press-statements).

Comment: Is the presumption that people who are going camping in groups of 4 won't be meeting up in each others back yards instead?

Comment: They might or they might not.  But I would presume they'd also expect more peer pressure from their neighbors if they did.  I tried looking for picture published about 3 weeks ago, of the top of the Squamish Chief trail.  There is a massive cliff there, with a granite ledge about the size of a basketball court.  Guess what?  Fully crowded in that picture, along with general outrage at the stupidity on display.

Comment: Dunno I see many of my neighbors partying in each others apartments and legally speaking no one can stop them. I'd much rather see those people go to a park.

Comment: "4 people? Errr, probably not." My family has 5 people. So it is possible.

Comment: "Oh, and I will own up to being a downvoter." Not sure how this is relevant to your answer. It might be better as a comment.

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot to edit that.  4 adults.  also, the OP seemed interested in why he's getting downvotes.

Comment: We're all considered adults now. So, again, it's still *technically* possible.

Answer (score 0):

The infection rate in Australia could hit zero pretty soon the way things are going and because we are an island and our borders are going to stay shut it makes sense to increase restrictions for a short time so we are able to completely eliminate the virus from our country. Then we will be able to slowly start lifting restrictions.  By that time our hospitals will be prepared for any new mass outbreaks